# Multiple DAO instances = Bad?

Tags: java, hibernate, soa, rmi, dao

Two application (A and B) use hibernate to retrieve the same entities out of a database. Should a DAO be instantiated in each application or should there be a separate application (C) that contains the only instance of the DAO and exposes a service (e.g. RMI) for A and B to use?

If the latter case is true then what is the common practise for preventing loading exceptions? I think my plan currently is to use RMI and create a DTO for each domain object. My only reservation is that entities in A and B won't be able to reference entities in C. Is this a common strategy?

Something that might be worth mentioning is that there a 4 different servers each running A and B. Currently each server has the DB on it too - this question came about because I'm trying to centralise something - either all projects have a DAO pointing to a single DB server or all applications point to a service hosted by C that has a DAO to a single DB.

Comment: I assume with "projects" you mean "applications"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it should be applications - I'll change it.

Answer (score 2):

A DAO is typically a stateless singleton used to load, search, modify and delete entities from the database. Why would you want to use RMI to communicate with another JVM just to do that? You would seriously decrease the performance, the entities would never be attached to the session, and you couldn't use transactions spanning more than a single operation (load, store) on a single entity. It just doesn't make sense.

Have a DAO instance in each of your application.

Comment: I'm obviously wrong so please forgive my ignorance - isn't this what happens in a SOA environment? There are a number of applications that are independent and other applications can ask them for data via SOAP/RMI/Hessian. The independent applications handle the tx, load balancing, service authentication etc

Comment: Yes, but you rarely have to have a global transaction spanning several calls to these various web services. That's not the case with a DAO, where, for example, transferring money from an account to another needs a single transaction to get account A, get accountB, remove amount from A, add amount to B, save A and save B. If you use a different transaction for each load and each save, you'll have serious problems in case one of them rolls back.

Comment: In the example you gave I would have an `AccountService` in C with a method `transferMoney(Long fromAccId, Long toAccId, Double amount)` that could be called by A or B. There are a limited number of things that can be done with an account; the service(s) could encompass all of those use cases. I was under the impression this is really common?

Comment: So in this case it's not DAOs that would be remotely accessible, but functional services implementing the business logic. This is a completely different story.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I should've been clearer - it was never my intention to expose a DAO over RMI. Given this, would you mind giving me your thoughts on the DTO approach.

Comment: It really depends on the applications. If A and C are tightly coupled, maybe it's best to have a single application, allowing transactions spanning both apps, and sharing persistent entities directly. If they are loosely coupled, an RMI or web service approach can be a good one. Or you could share the same database but have A only allowed to modify some part of it, while still seeing the other part, and C allowed to modify another common part. It's hard to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring and add this DAO instance bean to the parent application context for both of projects.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your achitecture.  Both approaches are possible and have advantages and disadvantages.
If you have one DAO and connecto to it via RMI / REST, you have decoupled using projects from hibernate, but introduced  some latency, imposed serializability on entities  and got single point of failure (can be solved by clustering )

If you each proejct has own DAO, you got come complexity from hibernate configuration  but avoided latency and sngle point of failure.

In both cases you shall take precautions to prevent condurent data modifcations and keep consistency ( like optimistic locking etc. )